# Why won't my servo motors stop spinning when trying to go forward?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I need to make this object following robot which uses 2 servo motors to move and a ultrasonic sensor to detect where objects are and where the Arduino should tell the servos to move. But, the problem seems to be that whenever the servo motors are trying to move forwards or backwards they just keep spinning. I've tried to check for loose wires but no wires seem loose, I've tried changing how I write the code but nothing has seemed to work yet...

**Also here's some relevant code (not all):**

```cpp
void forward() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos++)
  {
    for (pos2 = 0; pos2 <= 180; pos2++)
    {   
      myServo1.write(pos);
      myServo2.write(pos2);
      delay(15);
    }
  }
}

int Distance_thing() {
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(Trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(20);
  digitalWrite(Trig, LOW);
  float Fdistance = pulseIn(Echo, HIGH);
  Fdistance= Fdistance / 58;
  return (int)Fdistance;
}

void loop() {
  rightDistance = Distance_thing();
  leftDistance = Distance_thing();

  if ((rightDistance > 70) && (leftDistance > 70)) {
    stop();
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((rightDistance >= 20) && (leftDistance >= 20)) {
    forward();
    delay(500);
  }
  else if ((rightDistance <= 10) && (leftDistance <= 10)) {
    back();
    delay(500);
  }
  else if (rightDistance - 3 > leftDistance) {
    left();
    delay(500);
  }
  else if (rightDistance + 3 < leftDistance) {
    right();
    delay(500);
  }
  else {
    stop();
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `forward` function loops 181 times over another loop of 181 iterations, writing values to your servos every 15ms.  So, that's 32761 times.  When you call this function, the rest of your program will not be reached until this operation completes, which looks like it will take around 8.5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As paddy already pointed out your movements take very long.

The nested for loops will call `delay(15)` 181*181 times. That's 32716 times 15 milliseconds. A total of 8.2 minutes.

Another problem with your code is that you expect the servo to return from 180° to 0° within 15ms which is not going to happen.

Also don't need to call `myServo1.write(pos)` in the inner loop as `pos` is only updated in the outer loop. That's a total of 32580 uneccessary function calls.

You should learn how to write non-blocking code. There are plenty of resources available.
You might also develop a habit of checking your maths. Don't just delay. Think about what it actually means to delay `181*181*15ms`!

Comment: Alright thank you so much this really helped!